# R: Select rows by value and always include previous row

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

I'm trying to subset a data frame to all rows for which a certain column value is '13', but I want all rows preceding a row with '13' to be included too, no matter the value in that column.

I do not want a row to be included twice when it both precedes a row with '13' in the specific column, but also has the value '13' itself.

Here is an example data frame and solution, whereby the condition (subset rows to rows with time = 13 and (time=13)-1, without duplicating)

```
ID  speed   dist    time
A   4        12     4
B   7        10     8
C   7        18     13
C   8        4      5
A   5        6      13
D   6        2      13
E   7        2      9

Becomes

ID  speed   dist    time
B   7       10      8
C   7       18      13
C   8       4       5
A   5       6       13
D   6       2       13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a position index where 'time' value is 13 using `which` and then subtract 1 from the index and concatenate both to subset

```
i1 <- which(df1$time == 13) 
ind <- sort(unique(i1 - rep(c(1, 0), each = length(i1))))
ind <- ind[ind >0]
df1[ind,]
```

-output

```
  ID speed dist time
2  B     7   10    8
3  C     7   18   13
4  C     8    4    5
5  A     5    6   13
6  D     6    2   13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "D", "E"), speed = c(4L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L), dist = c(12L, 10L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 
2L), time = c(4L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 13L, 13L, 9L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
df <- read.table(text = '
ID  speed   dist    time
A   4        12     4
B   7        10     8
C   7        18     13
C   8        4      5
A   5        6      13
D   6        2      13
E   7        2      9
', header = TRUE)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.2

df %>% 
  filter(time == 13 | lead(time == 13))
#>   ID speed dist time
#> 1  B     7   10    8
#> 2  C     7   18   13
#> 3  C     8    4    5
#> 4  A     5    6   13
#> 5  D     6    2   13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `subset` + `diff`

```
> subset(df, time == 13 | c(diff(time == 13), FALSE))
  ID speed dist time
2  B     7   10    8
3  C     7   18   13
4  C     8    4    5
5  A     5    6   13
6  D     6    2   13
```